# Display:none en AMP no funciona

Tags: amp

Quiero ocultar un  en la versión AMP de un Prestashop.

Esto es lo que quiero ocultar. En HTML es así:

```
<div id="toc_container">
<p class="toc_title">LOREM IPSUM</p>
<ul class="toc_list">
<li><a class="encabezado_h2" href="#First_Point_Header">Lorem Ipsum</a>
<ul>
<li><a class="encabezado_h3" href="#First_Sub_Point_1">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
</ul>
</ul>
</div>
```

En los CSS del módulo de AMP de Prestashop estoy poniendo esto:

```
#toc_container {
    display:none;
}
```

¿Es correcto o estoy haciendo algo mal? No hay manera de que lo pille. Cuando hago pruebas en la consola del navegador y añado el display sí que funciona, por eso no entiendo nada. Estoy probando en incógnito por si es un tema de caché, pero no; tanto en Chrome como en Safari como en Firefox pasa lo mismo.

Comment: Hola. El código debería funcionar correctamente. Verifica que tu CSS esté correctamente vinculado a tu fichero HTML. Para forzar a tu navegador a volver a cargar la página puedes pulsar CTRL+F5 y ver si de esta forma se efectúan los cambios.

Comment: Tiene que estar vinculado bien porque hay otros estilos del documento que sí que coge. Creo que tiene que ver con que está pillando los estilos del user agent. Te paso la página AMP: https://sexydream.es/module/wkamp/categoryamp?idCategory=108&id_lang=1&id_shop=1

Comment: Pon tu `display:none` con `!important` de la siguiente forma: `display:none !important;` y verifica si así el estilo se aplica.

Comment: Nada, no funciona... Ni en incógnito, ni borrando la caché. El estilo ni siquiera sale en la consola del navegador, es como si lo ignorara completamente.